# Flex scrolling the canvas to its top

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, canvas, scroll

Is there a way to programmatically scroll the canvas to its topmost position?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`verticalScrollPosition = 0`

Comment: Don't forget that you might need to make the call *after* the screen refresh, which you can do by using callLater()

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=layoutperformance_12.html

Answer (score 0):

Try using DisplayObject's [scrollRect](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#scrollRect) property.